# Typeerror: must be real number, not list

Tags: python-3.x, list, trigonometry

I am trying to get the cosine inverse of a number. But it is showing an error message

```
for i in S:
    nr=[((i[0]*p)+(i[1]*q))/(math.sqrt(i[0]**2+i[1]**2)*math.sqrt(p**2+q**2)) for (p,q) in P]
    print(nr)
    dist=math.acos(nr)
```

The last statement is throwing an error "must be real number, not list"
However, nr is not a list. I am not sure what is the error

Request help in understanding this. Thanks in advance

Comment: It would help to know what is in `S`.

Comment: S and P are lists of tuples.
S=[(1,2),(3,4),(-1,1),(6,-7),(0, 6),(-5,-8)]
P=[(3,-4)]

Comment: The line that defines nr is a list comprehension, meaning that nr is a list. It's complaining because you can't do acos of a list. Try doing print(type(nr)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
nr=[((i[0]*p)+(i[1]*q))/(math.sqrt(i[0]**2+i[1]**2)*math.sqrt(p**2+q**2)) for (p,q) in P]
```

This, is a list comprehension, meaning that nr is a list. It's complaining because you can't do acos of a list.

As you said in your comment, P is a single element list, so your nr list contains only one element, but it's still a list. Try doing `math.acos(nr[0])`

Comment: @asspsss Great, would you mind accepting the answer?

Comment: the answer is not wrong, but does not solve the problem of dealing with a list of variables in situation like this

Comment: @GeorgiIvanovDimitrov The OP asked for “help understanding this”, and made the incorrect assertion that ‘nr is not a list’, all of which is explained by this answer. The OP did not ask how to deal with ‘nr’ being a multi-element list.